Joins where 1 table has duplicated entries
I have a database with a products table and another table product_details which has additional product details but this table also has historical entries for each product.
The key for both tables is the product_code.
For example:

Product table has product_code ABC123
product_details table has 8 entries for product_code ABC123

I need to link both tables together so I can see the product details, but only want to see the most recent entry in the product_details table
so if I do this:
SELECT
    prd.product_code,
    prd.description,
    dtls.price,
    dtls.last_update
FROM
    products prd
    INNER JOIN product_details dtls ON prd.product_code = dtls.product_code
WHERE
    prd.product_code = 'ABC123'

this will return many rows, I need 1 row... and I need it to work for all rows in the product table..
In code I can hit the product_details table with
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM product_details 
WHERE product_code = 'ABC123' 
ORDER BY last_update DESC

which will give me the single line that I need but this will be super inefficient if I have to do this for every item in the product table every time i need to view the data.
is there any way in SQL to join product table to just the most recent product_details entry?
Product



product_code
description




ABC123
Some Product


DEF321
Some Other Product



product_details



product_code
price
last_update




ABC123
123.45
01/01/2020


ABC123
113.45
01/02/2020


ABC123
122.45
01/03/2020


ABC123
133.45
01/04/2020


ABC123
144.45
01/05/2020


ABC123
125.45
01/06/2020


ABC123
103.45
01/07/2020


ABC123
93.45
01/08/2020


DEF123
143.45
01/01/2020


DEF123
133.45
01/02/2020


DEF123
113.45
01/03/2020


DEF123
103.45
01/04/2020


DEF123
193.45
01/05/2020



what I would like to be able to do is see something like this for every product in the products table:


row_number is your friend.

"this will be super inefficient" - eh?

Please show (not as images) sample data and desired results.

The pattern is something like: select * from headtable h outer apply (select top 1 * from detailtable d where d.ID = h.ID order by d.somecolumn DESC) d

a HTML to MARKDOWN converter is your friend....  (in this case: https://htmlmarkdown.com/ )

This approach uses a CTE to determine the latest product_details for each product_id - this approach isn't the most terse or succint, but I feel is more maintainable, and results in as-good an execution-plan as you'll get, provided you have an INDEX on product_details( product_code, last_update ).
Don't forget to schema-qualify your table references (hence the dbo. bit) and parameterize your own queries.
If you use this often, you can convert the latest CTE to a VIEW WITH SCHEMABINDING for easier reuse.
DECLARE @productCode nvarchar(50) = N'ABC123';

WITH latest AS (
    SELECT
        pd.product_code,
        MAX( pd.last_update ) AS last_update
    FROM
        dbo.product_details AS pd
    GROUP BY
        pd.product_code
)
SELECT
    p.*,
    pd.*
FROM
    dbo.products AS p
    INNER JOIN latest AS l ON l.product_code = p.product_code
    INNER JOIN product_details AS pd ON
        pd.product_code = l.product_code
        AND
        pd.last_update = l.last_update
     
WHERE
    p.product_code = @productCode;



I think, row_number() with order by desc is preferable in your case.
We can take only 1 row from details for join with master table.
See example
select p.product_code,p.description,pd.price,pd.last_update
from Product p
left join (
  select * 
     ,row_number()over(partition by product_code order by last_update desc) rn
  from product_details
 ) pd on pd.product_code=p.product_code and pd.rn=1

LEFT or INNER join - for your choice.



roduct_code
description
price
last_update




ABC123
Some Product
93.45
2020-01-08


DEF123
Some Other Product
193.45
2020-01-05


ghi123
Some Other Product
null
null



Or



roduct_code
description
price
last_update




ABC123
Some Product
93.45
2020-01-08


DEF123
Some Other Product
193.45
2020-01-05



Demo
